# Rearranging/ updating data in SQL Server (move back to front)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have a column called `data` that contains a row of letters such as `ABCDEFGH` but I want to update the entry to `EFGHABCD`.

How would I do that?

Basically I have a DOB in a non-date column (`varchar`) that is `mm/dd/yyyy`. I want to move the `yyyy` to before the `mm`. Then I'll run a replace command and delete the / leaving `yyyymmdd` .

Comment: Try googling for `sql server substring`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LEFT`, `RIGHT` function.

More : [T-SQL: RIGHT, LEFT, SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX Functions](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17948.t-sql-right-left-substring-and-charindex-functions.aspx)

Example:

```
select right('ABCDEFGH', 4) + left('ABCDEFGH', 4);
```

**UPDATE**

Here the step to update your DOB data to `yyyymmdd` format.

1. [CAST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) your DOB to date data type

   ```
   select cast('08/12/2014' as date);
   ```
2. [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) the previous result to varchar and then apply the style

   ```
   select convert(varchar, cast('08/12/2014' as date), 112);
   ```

   112 is the style. You can see the link that I provided for more explanation.

Comment: And if ABCDEFGH are just representational placeholders? Like I have 1 million rows of data in trying to move the last 4 letters to the front scenario.

Comment: Yes it's only a placeholders. The idea is to using `LEFT` and `RIGHT` function to get first 4 letter and last 4 character. Try to give more example in your question

Comment: Basically I have a DOB in a non-date column (varchar) that is mm/dd/yyyy. I want to move the yyyy to befor the mm. Then I'll run a replace command and delete the / leaving yyyymmdd  .

Comment: Iswanto, it doesn't seem to work  throws errors. the table is called testfile and the column is called DOB  I forgot to mention that so that's probably part of the error.

Comment: I only give you an example, so you need to modify that in your query ..:)

Comment: I'm horrible at this :( I ran select dbo.testfile cast('08/12/2014' as date); and get syntax error near 08/12/2014

Comment: It should like this : `select cast('08/12/2014' as date) from dbo.testfile`

Comment: I'm just getting errors select dob convert(varchar, cast('08/12/2014' as date), 112)  from dbo.testfile . I'm just so lost right now :/

Comment: Use this : `select convert(varchar, cast(dob as date), 112) from dbo.testfile`

Comment: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Make sure your dob data is a date with format like this : mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: they all are, but in a varchar column. I may have to dump it and change the type and re-import I think